# javascript syntax $

Tags: javascript

i'm reading a javascript source code , and i haven't written javascript before. i'm confused about some syntax of it.

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(function () {    

 window.onload=function()
 {
mkAjaxObj(0,0);
 }    
});

</script>
```

could you tell me , why the anonymous function is putted in the $( ), what is the use of $( ) , is the anonymous function will be called ? or will be execute automatically.

another one :

```
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
          [ { data: monkeyavgtime, label: "monkey average run time"}, { data: monkeymixtime, label: "monkey shortest run time" } ], 
          {
              series: {
              lines: { show: true },
              points: { show: true }
              },
              grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
              yaxis: { min: 0, max: maxtime },
              xaxis: {ticks:[[0,version[0]],[1,version[1]],[2,version[2]], [3,version[3]], [4,version[4]],[5,version[5]],[6,version[6]]]}
          });
```

1 : $.plot , what $. stand for ?

2 : $("#placeholder") 
    there is a tag in the html :
    
    
    dose $("#placeholder") is a reference to it ? but 
    is there any different with 
    var obj=document.getElementById("product") ?

thanks very much !

Comment: it supposed to attract dollars into your wallet (doesnt work, look at PHP salaries), in any other means it is valid characted for use in identifiers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` is just a variable name. There's not much special about it. It's commonly used in libraries such as jQuery and Prototype because it's short and easy to type.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript variable names may begin with a `$`, e.g. `$foo = 42`. It's also legal to name a variable as *just* a `$`.

Nothing in the JavaScript core language uses this name, but some JavaScript libraries (notably Prototype and jQuery) create a global variable named `$` that is a function with all sorts of extra functionality, including using CSS-like expressions to select elements in the DOM conveniently.

Comment: `$` doesn't even have to be only at the beginning — it's allowed anywhere in a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Here $ is probably the `jQuery` function. In javascript `$` is a valid name so some libraries just use it as an alias for another function, in this case `jQuery`. In this case the anonymous function is called by jQuery when the DOM has loaded. I would recommend reading some introductory javascript material.